# Is possible to simulate a <br/> without a <br/>?

Tags: css

Please, take a look to this piece of code:

```
<span class="something">
    <label>test1</label><br/>
    <label>test2</label><br/>
    <label>test3</label>
</span>
```

This will create a vertical list of labels. Is possible to do this without the `<br>` tags using CSS? It is, is possible to show the same vertical aligned label list with this HTML code?:

```
<span class="something">
    <label>test1</label>
    <label>test2</label>
    <label>test3</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Side note: this may be better off as a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements in it

Comment: @Pekka Only if it's a list! Otherwise, you're abusing the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements, which is just as bad as abusing tables.

Comment: @Mr yeah, true. Hence the *may*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, without changing the contents of the span to block elements:

```
span.something label:after {content: '\A'; white-space: pre-line}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/VsnKx/

Edit: Another way (if you don't mind floats) is

```
span.something label {float:left; clear:both}
```

which doesn't use `:after`, although it does use floats, which may be undesirable. You also will have to `clear` the first element after the `span`.

Comment: This is very nice because it retains `display: inline`, something none of the other solutions do. I'm not 100% sure about IE7/8 compatibility though? (on a Mac, can't test)

Comment: @Pekka `:after` isn't available in IE7

Comment: This is what I was looking. Other solutions don't work on examples like that: http://jsfiddle.net/VsnKx/1/ My app is not compatible with IE7, but must be with IE8. @Pekka do you know if this is IE8 compatible? (I'm also in Linux! :D)

Comment: @Ivan If you don't mind floats, you can try `span.something label {float:left; clear:both}` as in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsnKx/2/). Still not sure how IE handles that though. Anyone care to test?

Answer (score 8):

You could do this:

```
span.something label {
  display: block; /* as opposed to display: inline; */
}
```

This works because by default `<label>`s are `inline` elements. If you change them to display block they will display in a list with line breaks between them.

However this is probably a bad way to do what you want. What you really want is an unordered list:

```
<ul class="something">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>etc...</li>
</ul>
```

To get rid of the bullet points:

```
ul.something {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `display:block` for the `label`s, which will adjust them to be displayed on a new line.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/eZ8t5/

Comment: Won't this cause trouble because block elements in an inline element are illegal? Or was that for native element properties only? I can't remember, but I think you should make the span `display: block` too

Comment: @Pekka afaik it is for native elements only. That code validates as html5.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Use this css code:

```
span.something label{
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: If you are displaying as a `block` and not floating, then you don't need the `clear: both`. The `clear` is for floats.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways, those mentioned in other answers as well as setting `label { display: table-row}`. However, there is no apparent reason not to use `br` tags or `div` containers or a table in HTML, if you want the labels on separate lines, and no apparent reason for wanting that (what is a label without an associated input field?).

Comment: This is a simplified example :)

Comment: @Ivan, if you want to get help with your real problem, present the real problem and not an artificial, meaningless problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I disagree. Simplified examples are much easier to understand and to answer. Sure, the OP could have provided a link to his real website, but if this small snippet is what the problem boils down to, that's a good thing. All too often, people post their entire HTML and leave it to us to figure out where the problematic area is.